# Check if image with more than 2px exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I see if an image with 2px or more exist? Current code:

```
if( $("#imageID").length < 10) { 
   //Do something
   }
```

Comment: What is meaning of *image with 2px*?

Comment: You want to check its width and/or height?

Comment: if the image has 2 pixels width or more

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: DO you mean if *any* image exists that wider than 2px?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no just with the id imageID

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method

```
$("#imageID").width() > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use naturalWidth and naturalHeight property of the image element.

```
   if( document.getElementById("imageID").naturalWidth > 2) { // TO DO: do something
   }
```